# ASP.NET Gridview - On load the first row is missing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I using an ObjectDataSource (Should receive 5 rows) and a gridview.
When I open the gridview I received all rows except the first one. So I only see 4 rows.

Now I sorting my gridview with a click on a column. But I also get only 4 rows.

After selecting a filter I receive all 5 rows.

What could be the problem?

EDIT:

```
<cc1:myGridview ID="mgvTESTs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataSourceID="odsTESTs" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="USER" SortExpression="USER">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="zeile BtnZeile">
                    <asp:Label ID="lUSER" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TEST" SortExpression="TEST">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lTEST" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TEST") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bid" SortExpression="BID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lBID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DATER" SortExpression="DATER">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lDATER" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DATER") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ID"
            Visible="False" />
    </Columns>
</cc1:myGridview>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsTESTs" runat="server" SelectMethod="SQLSelectQuery"
    TypeName="ObjectDataSource_DataBoundControl">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="SqlCommand" DefaultValue="Select ID,
    TEST,
    BID,
    DATER
FROM 
    ABC_TESTs 
WHERE DATER >= '@param1' AND  DATER < '@param2'
ORDER BY DATER DESC" />
 <asp:SessionParameter Name="param1" Type="String" DefaultValue="01-01-2011"/>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="param2" Type="String" DefaultValue="01-01-2011"/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default select in your `ObjectDataSource` is probably only returning 4 rows, unless you are filtering it yourself in `RowDataBound`.

Can't be of anymore help without some code like @Aneef mentioned.